# GeoSPARQL for Apache Jena Fuseki

Tags: jena, fuseki, geosparql

Jena Fuseki works fine, but the GeoSPARQL version not so much (https://github.com/galbiston/geosparql-fuseki).

It'll fire up (supposedly)

```
11:12:46 INFO  GeosparqlServer :: GeoSPARQL Server: Running - Port: 3030, Dataset: /ds, Loopback Only: true,  Allow Update: false
11:12:46 INFO  Server          :: Start Fuseki (port=3030)
```

I tend to use Postman to test these kind of things, but http://localhost:3030 just returns a 404.

So my first question is whether it's really actually running or not. It would appear that it isn't.

My second question (for when it is running) relates to getting data into it. There's not front-end of the thing but a command line command of:

`s-put http://localhost:3030/ default geonames.ttl`

But s-put doesn't appear to be an executable, so how does one call it?

Comment: galbiston/geosparql-fuseki isn't the currentsystem.

Builds are at:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jena/jena-fuseki-geosparql/

http://localhost:3030 - in the GeoSPARQL server there isn't a UI by default so that page is 404. The data is at http://localhost:3030/ds.

Then its seems to be a read-only server. I hope data comes from the configuration file.

s-put http://localhost:3030/ds default geonames.ttl

s-put is a ruby script and you may need to make it executable especially if from a zip file.

Comment: Thanks. Well, July here and it still doesn't work (for me). I did get it to load some data from the github version but the data seems odd to me (lat/long co-ordinates are the middle of the sea) and all queries to far return zero results.